# Is it possible to pipeline .NET methods in a script language

Tags: c#, .net, pipeline

I am wondering if there is any language feature/library/tools/techniques I could use to call .NET/C# "functions" in a pipeline in a scripting environment? For example, I have

```
public interface IFoo
{
    ...
}

public interface IBar
{
    IFoo Load(string fileName);
    IFoo Replace(string oldValue, string newValue);
    void Save(string fileName);
}
```

Then wrap them in util.exe with proper Main(). Now I want to use them like piped DOS command:

```
util.exe -load in.txt | util.exe -replace x y | util.exe -save output.txt
```

Is it possible? Is there any constraint on `IFoo` because it can be complex data structure that can't be easily serialized to ASCII string. What's the way to get there?

Comment: Normally you'd just use `.`. But your example doesn't make sense. How would you call an `IBar` method on an `IFoo`?

Comment: @CodesInChaos, my example may not make sense but I think my ask is clear. I can write a Main() wrapper to instantiate a Bar instance, or these methods can be static, not on an interface. I guess the core of my question is what is the tooling to pipeline .NET runtime input/output.

Comment: @MitchWheat, I'm not familiar with PS, is it easy to adapt existing C# library methods into PS cmdlets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell is very good option.

First of all you can call any compiled code directly, so if you don't want to make actual cmdlets in C# you can write calling code in PowerShell and use all its pipeline plumbing to pass data between steps.

I.e. calling Ping.Send:

```
$ping = New-Object System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
$ping.send("localhost")
```

You can also implement CmdLets for nice PowerShell code and greater control - sample http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32999/How-to-Write-a-Custom-PowerShell-Cmdlet-Part-I

Answer (score 1):

One good option is C# Script

http://www.csscript.net/

That allows you to call any .NET assembly from a scripting environment, where the language of the scripting environment is C#.

> CS-Script is a CLR (Common Language Runtime) based scripting system which uses ECMA-compliant C# as a programming language. CS-Script currently targets Microsoft implementation of CLR (.NET 2.0/3.0/3.5/4.0) with full support on Mono.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use F# for this. You can use [pipes and function composition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/functions/#function-composition-and-pipelining) for sequential data processing and it is a .NET language so you can directly reference C# and VB objects. You can use it both in [scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/tools/fsharp-interactive/#scripting-with-f) and a REPL prompt, and the interpreter is included in the .NET SDK by default.